# S3 Batch Operation : object tagging fails when created via batch operation ui

Tags: amazon-s3, s3-object-tagging

While creating a batch job to tag all the objects in a manifest file, I get the following error
"The job report could not be written to your report bucket. Please check your permissions"

I am using the same bucket for reports as well.

Also, I have added the necessary permissions to create job, get object, put object, put object tag etc.

I am not able to find a solution online.

Comment: Can you post the permissions attached to the role?

Answer (score 1):

To allow the S3 Batch Operations service principal to assume the IAM role edit the Trust Policy on the IAM Role you are using.

See **Trust Policy** here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops-iam-role-policies.html